# jquery ui datepicker font size is huge

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

im trying to add a datepicker to my symfony application and i got it working, but the size of the datepicker is about 3 times bigger than normal (on the demo page). I have not edited any CSS, i just used the default ui lightness theme no modifications.

Does anybody have any idea why the size is blown up so big?

CSS:

http://paste2.org/p/835414

tough i doubt that will be very usefull.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Modify `font-size` in the `.ui-widget` class. Change it from `1.1em` (the current value) to something less, like `1em` or `0.9em`. Or just use a static size, like `12px`, but that's not recommendable.

Comment: genius!

But why would the font be so much bigger? I did not edit anything in the CSS just downloaded it from the jquery UI website...

Comment: It's because the font was specified in `em`, which is context-dependent. For example, if you have `font-size: 14px` on your `body` and then on a `div` you have `1em`, that `div` will basically be `14px`. If, on the `div`, you have `0.8em`, it will be smaller. If then you change `body` to `12px`, the `div` will be even smaller. Basically, `em` is like a ratio (`%`) where `1em == 100%` (if I'm wrong someone correct me).

Comment: that may be obvious to most, but you have to add !important to the CSS so that it overrides the one from jquery UI. I put in my CSS: .ui-widget { font-size: 0.8em !important; } -- it wouldn't work without the !important.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery you don't *have* to (and it's not recommended either -- `!important` should only be used in extreme cases). If you use the same selector that is used in jQuery's CSS and load your custom CSS *after* jQuery's, your style should apply even without `!important`. Better yet, you can modify jQuery's CSS file directly.